# android auto boot an application and followed by a splash screen

Tags: android, onresume, splash-screen

I'm new to android, bear with me if my question is stupid.
I have application which has a 5 seconds splash screen at the beginning.
My application is auto booted when the device's powered on. which means, after I power on the device, the timer for splash screen starts to count in background. If I unlock the screen after 5 seconds, the splash screen is gone. 
I want the timer starts counting only when the activity has been brought to the front. I tried

```
onResume()
```

but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do not piss off your users. and enforcing them to see the splash is just pissing them off

Comment: Splash screens are evil! http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=632